# BOOST query in search option

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

when I use constraints with boot query, then boost is being ignored.. following is my options file

```xml
let $options := 
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <constraint name="gs">
    <value>
      <element ns="http://xxxx/entity/target" name="gene-symbol"/>
    </value>
  </constraint>
  <constraint name="taxid">
    <value>
      <element ns="http://xxx/entity/target/species" name="taxonomy-id"/>
    </value>
  </constraint>
  <constraint name="search-text">
    <custom facet="false">
      <parse apply="parse-string"
             ns="http://xxx/xxx/custom-constraints/dads/dadsAutosuggestConstraint"
             at="/lib/custom-constraints/dads/dadsAutosuggestConstraint.xqy"/>
    </custom>
  </constraint>
  <term>
    <default ref="search-text" />
    <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
    <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
    <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
    <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
  </term>
</options>
```

when I do

`let $q := 'gs:PARP1 BOOST (taxid:9606)'`

the boost is ignored .. but when do without constraint

`let $q := 'PARP1 BOOST (taxid:9606)'`

it works like expected..

How can I make it work with `constraints` as well

**** UPDATED with search plan ******

```xml
<search:plan>
    <qry:query-plan xmlns:qry="http://marklogic.com/cts/query">
      <qry:expr-trace>impl:apply-search(map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../&gt;), "xdmp:plan", fn:false())</qry:expr-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Analyzing path for search: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Path is fully searchable.</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Gathering constraints.</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:elem-word-trace text="PARP1" elem-name="gene-symbol" elem-uri="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target">
    <qry:key>4322900364588965241</qry:key>
      </qry:elem-word-trace>
      <qry:info-trace>Search query contributed 1 constraint: cts:boost-query(cts:element-word-query(fn:QName("http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target","gene-symbol"), "PARP1", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target/species","taxonomy-id"), "9606", ("lang=en"), 1))</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:partial-plan>
    <qry:and-two-queries ordered="true">
      <qry:term-query weight="1">
        <qry:key>4322900364588965241</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>element(http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target:gene-symbol,word("PARP1"))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:or-two-queries>
        <qry:term-query weight="1">
          <qry:key>3406225445527486620</qry:key>
          <qry:annotation>element(taxonomy-id,value("9606"))</qry:annotation>
        </qry:term-query>
        <qry:and-query ordered="true"/>
      </qry:or-two-queries>
    </qry:and-two-queries>
      </qry:partial-plan>
      <qry:info-trace>Executing search.</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:ordering/>
      <qry:final-plan>
    <qry:and-query>
      <qry:and-two-queries ordered="true">
        <qry:term-query weight="1">
          <qry:key>4322900364588965241</qry:key>
          <qry:annotation>element(http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target:gene-symbol,word("PARP1"))</qry:annotation>
        </qry:term-query>
        <qry:or-two-queries>
          <qry:term-query weight="1">
        <qry:key>3406225445527486620</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>element(taxonomy-id,value("9606"))</qry:annotation>
          </qry:term-query>
          <qry:and-query ordered="true"/>
        </qry:or-two-queries>
      </qry:and-two-queries>
    </qry:and-query>
      </qry:final-plan>
      <qry:info-trace>Selected 6 fragments to filter</qry:info-trace>
      <qry:result estimate="6"/>
    </qry:query-plan>
  </search:plan>
```

Comment: Have you looked at changing the `gs` constraint from `value` to `word`?

Comment: I tried both :) .. same

Comment: If you add `<return-plan>true</return-plan>` to the options, can you post what is returned from both?

Comment: updated with search plan

Comment: Good to see you seem to have found a solution, but to be honest, I'm rather confused about the question. What is actually being 'boosted', and in what way should it be 'boosted'? Presuming you really are trying to boost something, either with weights, or with some kind of boost-query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested..once I changed the scoring to `score-simple` it worked. Added the following to my `search-options`

```xml
<search-option>score-simple</search-option>
```

By default it was doing `logft` and this was causing issues..

fyi: `<search-option>relevance-trace</search-option>` this option will tell you how the scores are being calculated